# Cookie won't take correct value on chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies, setcookie

I have a cookie problem on Chrome.
I use the setcookie() function in php as a mean to automatically re-authenticate users that have already gone through an authentification process (using LinkedIn API).

Problem is, the cookies I set work fine on Firefox an IE 11 but seem to get deleted after a few seconds on Chrome. I have tested that with a bunch of users, same problem for them (I'm waiting for feedback on other browsers).

Here is the code that sets the cookies:

```
setcookie('CookieID', $var, (time()+365*24*3600), NULL, NULL, false, true);
setcookie('LinkedInAuth', $var, (time()+365*24*3600), NULL, NULL, false, true);
```

Is it a known issue ? How can I resolve this ?

**EDIT 5:**

I changed the topic's title as I completely reviewed my approach. (I also deleted former edits as they were irrelevant)
Instead of using the LinkedIn ID as the value for my cookie, I now generate a unique ID using `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` function.
Here is the new code:

```
$random = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);
$UserKey = bin2hex($random);
$expiration= time() + 365*24*3600;
setcookie('CookieID', $UserKey, $expiration, NULL, NULL, false, false);
```

So now, Chrome is creating a cookie with a random value, as asked, and the cookie expiration time is right. Still, it is not the correct value! I echo `$UserKey` in the console and it has a diferent value from the cookie. But on FF and IE it's working like a charm!
The Response header gives me the wrong value for my cookie but the request header has the right one.

Does someone has any experience with that? Does the issue come from my code or the function I'm using?

Comment: Have you tried putting the calculation in a separated variable, something like $expire=time()+31536000?
`setcookie('CookieID', $var, (time()+$expire), NULL, NULL, false, true);`

Comment: I just tried that, same problem. Tried with both `$expiration= time()+31536000` and `$expiration = 31536000`

Comment: The issue is trivial - `$var` is **not set** in PHP, no matter what you say. If it were, the value would be sent. You even came up with a test that proved it. The only other possibility is that `$var` contains values that mess up cookie parsing, which is why values that you send should be encoded.

Comment: Yes but as I said before, the issue only happens in Chrome. I don't have the problem in FF or IE.

Comment: I just tried something, if i change the value of $var to just 'test' it works. So something must be wrong for chrome with the value I sent before, which is an ID looking like that: bg_h-F3Hl

Comment: You're thinking that it's the browser's fault - it isn't. If the other two browser can work with some value and the third can't - that just means two browsers accounted for possible human mistake. What you have to do is fix the actual issue, which is what's contained in that `$var` variable. Since your question doesn't state what that variable contains or where its contents comes from or what its value even *is*, it's easy to conclude that it's the value in it what's wrong but not *why*.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me on Chrome version 52.*something* on Linux:

```
$var = '1234567890';
setcookie('CookieID', 'CK'.$var, (time()+365*24*3600), NULL, NULL, false, true);
echo 'Cookie "CookieID" should be set to "CK'.$var.'"';
exit;
```

Here is the result: [image: Cookie test in Chrome]

I can only assume you are either not setting `$var` correctly or not setting `$var` before the rendering of the page (`setcookie()` is a `header` function and must be called before rendering the page).

Are you doing something different to the above code?

Comment: `$var= 'SomeString';
/*SET COOKIE*/
     $expiration= time() + 365*24*3600;
     setcookie('CookieID', $var, $expiration, NULL, NULL, false, false);
     /************/`

This is my code. I thought like you that I had set $var wrong, but since it works on FF and IE and even on Chrome i get output the value of $var, I don't see why this shouldn't work when I set the cookie.

Comment: Are you running  any extensions in Chrome? Maybe you are running Chrome in _Incognito_ mode? Under _Settings -> Advance -> Privacy -> Content Settings -> Cookies_ do you have any "exceptions" set?

Comment: No exceptions, no incognito. I was running an extension to montior cookies but I deleted it.
Actually there is something I thought of.
I get the value for $var from a CURL HTTP request, which is called and closed before I set the cookies. I didn't bother to look into this before since it's working on other browsers but since the problem seems to come from the value I give to $var, maybe Chrome is handling the request in a way that causes the issue?
Also, if I look in the Request headers, the Cookie values are the right ones. it's in the Response headers that they appear as deleted.

Comment: Wacky idea, set the cookie using Javascript (in `window.onload`) and see what happens.